# SQL QUERY: The locations of each department and the number of employees working in each location

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve this query, I have to find the locations for each department and the number of employees per location (not for department, common query for this database)

```
SELECT DE.DLOCATION, count(E.DNO)
 FROM DEPARTMENT D
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON D.DNUMBER = E.DNO
INNER JOIN DEPT_LOCATIONS DE ON DE.DNUMBER = E.DNO 
 GROUP BY DE.DLOCATION
/
```

This works but this shows me the number of employees per department (with possible repetitions of the value)

How can i get the number of employees for locations and not for department?

EDIT: The query works, i actually get the number of employees per location but in every city there is more than one department so if in the 'software' department of Houston there are 14 employees, then again in the 'software' department of Sugarland it shows me 14 employees so the query works but not per location, it works per department. Thank you anyway for your help i appreciate it

Comment: You query looks like it is doing what you want.  You need to provide sample data and desired results to explain what you really want.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Oracle. Added it to the tag list.

Answer (score 0):

You are closer to the solution. Since you haven't posted about other columns in these tables like employee ID or number. Going by what you have, try:

```
SELECT E.DNO, DE.DLOCATION, count(E.DNO)
FROM DEPARTMENT D
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E 
 ON D.DNUMBER = E.DNO
INNER JOIN DEPT_LOCATIONS DE 
 ON DE.DNUMBER = E.DNO 
GROUP BY E.DNO,DE.DLOCATION
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work as written what you need is `distinct` if i am not wrong.

```
SELECT DE.DLOCATION, COUNT(distinct E.DNO) as NoOfEmps
FROM DEPARTMENT D INNER JOIN 
     EMPLOYEE E 
     ON D.DNUMBER = E.DNO INNER JOIN 
     DEPT_LOCATIONS DE 
     ON DE.DNUMBER = E.DNO 
GROUP BY DE.DLOCATION;
```

Perhaps you need :

```
SELECT DE.DLOCATION, COUNT(*) as NoOfEmps
. . .
```

Comment: Yes i tried the 'distinct' but then it shows me that there is 1 employee per location

Comment: Still same problem, the number of employees is repeated, so it shows me more than 40 employees in total because most of the departments are located in more than 1 city

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SQL> SELECT D.loc, COUNT(E.Deptno) as NoOfEmps
  2  FROM DEPT D INNER JOIN EMP E 
  3       ON D.DEPTNO = E.DEPTNO
  4   GROUP BY D.LOC;
```

```
LOC             NOOFEMPS
------------- ----------
NEW YORK               3
CHICAGO                6
DALLAS                 5
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).